# How to improve the reliability of KF estimation?

Tags: kalman-filters

Sorry for boring you my dear friends.

Rcently I'm taking advatage of the state estimates X, outcoming from a Kalman Filter, with the their statistical information, i.e. Matrix of covariance P, to implement other studies.

Theories and practical studies have shown that the quality of KF state estimates is severely depending on the 'correctness' of system modeling, while unfortunately the true situation is unknown. Generally, the KF is either too optimistic or too pessimistic about the state accuracy, i.e. the state covariance matrix P.

The question is therefore, is there any method to reflect the variation of state estimates or the reality on the state covariance matrx P?

Thank you in advance for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For very long times, ive used the KF as a parametrized estimator, training the noise matrices, fitting them standard conditions. Just like a "neural net" on the covariance noises. And you have killer results ;).

And the method?... I've applied any standard nonlinear, gradient descent optimization algorithm, such as Newton Raphson, Levenberg Marquardt...

Sweet, simple, unexpected, and excelent results :). Though unpublishable xd.

If you have data, we can try them...

Comment: very interesting. Can you please elaborate on the process of optimizing the covariances. Thanks. nr1455@gmail.com

Comment: I will formalize it in the answer :)..

Comment: Also: why do you think it's in publishable? :(

Comment: "Hey i am having yet another method for setting up Q in the KF"!

Comment: pretty please?:)

Comment: I am really sorry for the delay.. I am just returning from a trip. I will write as soon as i can :)

Comment: thank you for your attention on this question. A little shame on me for stealing my husband's reputation (eventhough still a beginer in this community, still higher compared to me. I don't even have the right to post a comment...) to gain your attention. Before providing you the data, I wanna to emphasize that it would be my last choice to change the modeling of the KF via which the estimates $X$ and the vc-matrix $P$ are obtained. I know that a more realistic modeling of the system would be beneficial or another more sophisticated estimator could work better than KF. But, for this moment none

Comment: @user345696 My best guess is that you intended what you posted to be a comment on this answer, however there's not enough room. The right way to add the information would be as an edit to the original question (via your husband's account).

Comment: @hypfco pretty please with sugar on top?;)